# Bootstrap Navbar Dropdowns opening the first dropdown every time

Tags: html, css

Below is code snippet from a navbar, where some of the list items are dropdowns. There are three tabs for the navigation below. Two of them are Dropdowns. However, the dropdown feature only works when there is JUST ONE of the list items that is dropdown-capable.

When You make multiple dropdown, then whenever you click the dropdown, the first one always opens. So in this case "chapter2" will always dropdown, even if you are selecting the third item.

```
//First Nav Element
<li id="chapter1" class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  <p>TITLE HERE</p>
<li>

//Second Nav Element
<li id="chapter1" class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  <p>TITLE HERE</p>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu show">
    <li>
      <p>SUBTITLE 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <pSUBTITLE 2</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

//Third Nav Element
<li id="chapter2" class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
  <p>TITLE HERE</p>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu show">
    <li>
      <p>SUBTITLE 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <pSUBTITLE 2</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: either include more code or make a jsfiddle so that we can reproduce the issue...

Comment: there's also errors in your code: `<pSUBTITLE 2</p>` is missing `>` after `<p`

Comment: try removing "show" class from : <ul class="dropdown-menu show">